# How can I expand filesystem partition (ext4) ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ext4

I need help in expanding a filesystem partition. I am now on dual boot Windows 10 (SSD) + Ubuntu 22.04 (HDD). I noticed that Ubuntu was installed on HDD as be seen below: [image: gparted]

**I accidentally moved 50GB of unallocated space into /dev/sda2** while trying to extend my /dev/sda3 partition. I am trying to look into Q&A but can't sure about the solution. I don't wanna mess around and ended up wiping my entire HDD. However, my questions is:

1. How do I shrink and move 45GB from /dev/sda2 to unallocated space?
2. How do I expand my ext4? (from what I understand, you need to spare adjacent unallocated space around ext4, but I can't move and drag over the partition)

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Leaving 2 GB for esp is a lot. 500 Mb should be plenty enough.

Comment: Solved! Thank you guys for giving responses, I ended up using gparted + minitool partition wizard (Windows). For those who wondering, basically to move certain sizes, you need to slice it like a birthday cake, and merge it later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have good backups? And major change means you backup must be current.

Shrink you FAT32 partition, leaving 100 to 500MB. Ubuntu may be using ESP on Windows drive, but I like to have ESP on every drive, but not required.

Reboot & make sure everything is ok.

Then you should be able to move sda3 left into unallocated space.
This is the process that can take a while as all data is copied. Any interruption where part of data is copied corrupts it and only recovery is from backup.

Then you can expand sda3 right. That should be quick.

While gparted lets you queue steps, best to run each step & make sure it works before doing next one.

Comment: To run each step and check is good advice. Forgot to mention that.

Comment: I can't shrink FAT32 partition, last time I try with Ubuntu live too  see: https://tinypic.host/i/yIhzh

Comment: Is it getting mounted? Or does it have corruption and needs dosfsck? Does gparted show yellow or red icon? And right click on icon for info?

Comment: It isn't mount because I boot into Try Ubuntu. It can't shrink because the arrow doesn't move like it stuck. I ended up shrinking through windoes :D

Comment: Windows may have set something. So using Windows was a good option for FAT32.

Answer (score 3):

Use the usb device you used to install Ubuntu.

1. Choose `try Ubuntu`.
2. Use GParted to shrink sda2.
3. Check the UUID of sda3 and write it down/make a note in Kate e.g.
4. Then move sda3 to the left.
5. Expand sda3 with the unallocated space. This should now be on the right side of sda3.
6. Check the UUID of sda3 again. If it is the same you don't have to do anything more.
7. If it changed you need to change your `fstab` and `grub.cfg`. Just
   change the old number of the UUID for the new one ( as root ). Because you didn't delete sda2 I don't think the UUID will change though.